# Flyway's way of versioning files within clearcase

Tags: clearcase, flyway

Recently our development team are wanting to use Flyway as database deployment tool. Flyway requires some version numbers to be prepended to the files. Developers want to check in the version pre-pended files into the Clearcase. Our argument has been why do you need to version the files inside the versioning tool.

Has anyone used Flyway and Clearcase? If so how are you all doing it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to version those files if you cannot generate them.

But you shouldn't version them with version number, but rather put that information in an extra file, also versioned, which you can use in order to copy the other  files in a separate folder, with the right naming convention.

Comment: Thanks! Yes! That is what we are suggesting them..to create a version.txt file and put the version information there instead of adding version to the filename and then generating the files based on that.